# Forgotten a word. It means something like 'plan ruiner/foiler' and I'm pretty sure it starts with m, maybe ma/me

Tags: single-word-requests

Says it all in the title.

Forgotten a word. It means something like 'plan ruiner/foiler' and I'm pretty sure it starts with m, maybe ma/me.

It's a noun, of course. I've tried to search it up to no avail. Maybe I just suck at research.

Comment: Are you thinking of Scooby-doo villains and their "If not for you **meddling** kids and that stupid dog"?

Comment: @DanBron I forgot I asked this question but I think this was it lol thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In American English, the word **marplot** means a person who ruins a plan. Merriam-Webster defines the [term](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marplot) as

> one who frustrates or ruins a plan or undertaking by meddling

Comment: That’s a pretty uncommon word.